# Jquery Styles and Colors

Tags: jquery, css, styles

How can I use Jquery to create styles for my elements? We have to make a table and give the cells certain back-ground color. I was wondering wheter or not i can use the addClass() method. I have to give the cells styles without the use of css. It can't be by using CSS to make give the cells of the table styles. This is going to be due in 2 days so I would appreciate a response as soon as possible.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h1").mouseenter(function() {
$("#celery").addClass("apple ");   
 $("#beetroot").addClass("pear "); 
  });

$("th").mouseenter(function(){                                                  
    $("th").css({"background-color": "red", "font-size": "200%"});  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
     * {font-family: "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;}
            table, th, td {
                border: 3px solid blue;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            table {
                margin:auto;
            }
            td {
                width: 5%;
                padding: 10px;
                font-size: 10pt;
                text-align: center;
            }
            h1 {text-align: center}
       
        .celery {
           background-color:red
            
        }
        
        </style>
        
        
        <body class="siblings">
<h1>Unit 4 Say 4 Andrew Hu</h1>
    <table>
   <tr id="celery">
    <th>Wisconsin</th> 
    <th>Kentucky</th>
    <th>Maryland</th>
    <th>Maine</th>
    <th>New York</th>
    <th>Texas</th>
    <th> Califronia</th>
    <th>Virginia</th>
    </tr> 

  <tr id="beetroot" >
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td> 
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
   <td id="celery" >Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td> 
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="beetroot" >
   <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td> 
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="celery">
   <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td> 
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px">></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="beetroot">
   <td>Praesent mi quam</td> 
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="celery">
   <td>gula tristique semper</td> 
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="beetroot">
    <td>South</td> 
    <td>Park</td>
    <td>is</td>
    <td>an</td>
    <td>amazing</td>
    <td>show</td>
    <td>unlike</td>
    <td>Family Guy</td>
    </tr>  
    </table>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h1").mouseenter(function() {
$("#celery").addClass("apple ");   
 $("#beetroot").addClass("pear "); 
  });

$("th").mouseenter(function(){                                                  
    $("th").css({"background-color": "red", "font-size": "200%"});  
  });



});

    </script>
</head>

<h1>Unit 4 Say 4 Andrew Hu</h1>
    <table>
   <tr id="celery">
    <th>Wisconsin</th> 
    <th>Kentucky</th>
    <th>Maryland</th>
    <th>Maine</th>
    <th>New York</th>
    <th>Texas</th>
    <th> Califronia</th>
    <th>Virginia</th>
    </tr> 

  <tr id="beetroot" >
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td> 
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
   <td id="celery" >Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td> 
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="beetroot" >
   <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td> 
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="celery">
   <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td> 
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px">></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="beetroot">
   <td>Praesent mi quam</td> 
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="celery">
   <td>gula tristique semper</td> 
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="beetroot">
    <td>South</td> 
    <td>Park</td>
    <td>is</td>
    <td>an</td>
    <td>amazing</td>
    <td>show</td>
    <td>unlike</td>
    <td>Family Guy</td>
    </tr>  
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it in this way

```
$("th").mouseenter(function(){  
    $(this).css({"background-color": "red", "font-size": "200%"});  
  });
});
```

Check demo below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h1").mouseenter(function() {
      $("#celery").addClass("apple ");   
      $("#beetroot").addClass("pear "); 
  });

$("th").mouseenter(function(){  
    $(this).css({"background-color": "red", "font-size": "200%"});  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
     * {font-family: "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;}
            table, th, td {
                border: 3px solid blue;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            table {
                margin:auto;
            }
            td {
                width: 5%;
                padding: 10px;
                font-size: 10pt;
                text-align: center;
            }
            h1 {text-align: center}
       
        .celery {
           background-color:red
            
        }
        
        </style>
        
        
        <body class="siblings">
<h1>Unit 4 Say 4 Andrew Hu</h1>
    <table>
   <tr id="celery">
    <th>Wisconsin</th> 
    <th>Kentucky</th>
    <th>Maryland</th>
    <th>Maine</th>
    <th>New York</th>
    <th>Texas</th>
    <th> Califronia</th>
    <th>Virginia</th>
    </tr> 

  <tr id="beetroot" >
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td> 
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
   <td id="celery" >Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td> 
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    <td>Etiam scelerisque ex et dignissim semper.</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="beetroot" >
   <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td> 
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/Rfe6JpT1ILQa9Z81ap/source.gif" width="100px"></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="celery">
   <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td> 
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px">></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    <td><img src="http://southparkstudios.mtvnimages.com/shared/characters/kids/kyle-broflovski.png" width ="100px"></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="beetroot">
   <td>Praesent mi quam</td> 
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    <td>Praesent mi quam</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="celery">
   <td>gula tristique semper</td> 
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    <td>gula tristique semper</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="beetroot">
    <td>South</td> 
    <td>Park</td>
    <td>is</td>
    <td>an</td>
    <td>amazing</td>
    <td>show</td>
    <td>unlike</td>
    <td>Family Guy</td>
    </tr>  
    </table>
```